# Signalr Logging

Tags: logging, signalr, eventlog-source

After enabled Logging of SignalR component through adding a <system.diagnostic> section to the web.config of my app, i've experienced the following problems:

1. if logging is configured to log into a text file, it works fine, but no date / time is logged (?)
2. if logging is configured to log to eventlog, and i added the event source manually, the eventlog can't find the "event message file" or the file (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll) does not contain the error descriptions of SignalR Events.

anybody knows, how to configure logging for signalr in a more detailed way ?
br
Manfred

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?

Comment: Hi !  we are using version 2.4.2.0. Anyhow, after i disabled logging to eventlog and afterwards enable it again, we see correct messages.

Answer (score 0):

After changing logging to textfiles and added the parameter "datetime" as "traceoptions", the date und time is logged in the logfile

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.traceoptions?view=net-6.0

But, after enabling eventlog logging again, we didn't get the error reg. missing the eventlogmessages.dll again.
sorry, don't know, why it works now. Didn't change anything.
kind regards
Manfred